# My site disappeared from Google search, how long does it take to get back?

Tags: seo, google-search

Due to damage by malicious code, Google wrote:

> Google Analytics web property: link has been removed from http://swebdizajn.com  November 29, 2011
>
> Your Webmaster Tools http://swebdizajn.com  site is no longer linked to a Google Analytics web property. Possible reasons are:
>
> - You are no longer the owner of the site in Google Analytics, and nobody else owns both the site and the property
> - Another site owner removed the link.

After that I restored to backup and then accepted the Google message to tell them that all is well. How long will I have to wait for my site to return to the position where I was?

Answer (score 1):

[There is no set timetable](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=163633). The best you can do is clean it up quickly and [place a re-inclusion request](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=168328). Then you get to wait...

Comment: The site is cleaned before and 7 days on the white list - but this morning he took off the site with the search. Google appears to me now:

"Your site is now http://www.swebdizajn.com/ linked to a Google Analytics web property. November 29, 2011 ...

I am in a dilemma - why I responded so quickly when there is no site in search? I think this is difficult to understand. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Sweb who is "he"? And what do you mean by "took off the site with the search"?

Answer (score 0):

My experience with situations like this has varied. In most cases, sites I've had problems with got reindexed in about 10 days on average. Sometimes it's taken longer depending on how the site's been flagged since some require manual intervention to remove. The worst case I've had was about a year after requesting reconsideration on a domain that had been used for a linking scheme by the previous owner.