# Help! Google analytics removed and don't know why

Tags: google, analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My site disappeared from Google search, how long does it take to get back?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22658/my-site-disappeared-from-google-search-how-long-does-it-take-to-get-back)

I got this message:

Google Analytics web property: link has been removed from http://aglassmenagerie.net 
etc. etc.

I don't know why or what I should do to fix this.  I have been trying to add stuff to my site on a regular basis.  How do I find out what the problem is and how to fix it?

I am a stained glass artist and have an online store.  I am not that knowledgeable about this stuff. Someone please look at my site or code and tell me what I did wrong.

Pam

Comment: Your google analytics tag is still in place, can you log in to analytics? Do you have a webmaster tools account?

Comment: Yes, I can log in.  I do have a webmasters account.  I just got that message from Google after I logged in.  I might have had a duplicate number?  Looks like the others are still there.  My page still shows up on search.  If they are dumping me will it happen immediately?  Wish Google would tell you what you are doing wrong. I would fix it if I knew what to fix.  Could it have anything to do with the new sitemap I uploaded?  Seems like  I got that message right after I uploaded the new sitemap.  Do you see anything wrong?